# Viewing active and background apps graphics simultaneously

Tags: ios, ipad

Is it possible to superimpose the graphics from an active app on top of a background app and view both simultaneously on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

No by no methods is this possible beyond epic jail breaking.

Comment: Would jailbreaking even allow you to run multiple apps simultaneously?  Thats not something the core OS allows except for certain specific circumstances

Comment: once jailbroken you can run root and sudo commands so technically the sky is the limit. But it would probably be outrageously difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, the answer is no.**